# Manipulate messy input strings and convert it to custom output using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need your help. I have many types of string input to be manipulate on another form. Sure, it will be many string input styles (messy) or even copy and paste from third party software into my CKeditor editor.

Here's my codes to manipulate the input string to change to another form. In my case the output of each words will be in `<span>` tag.

```
function generate_answer_span($str="")
{
    $arr_words = preg_split('/ +/', $str);
    $arr_str = [];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr_words);
    echo '</pre>';
    foreach($arr_words as $word)
    {
        $word = strip_tags($word);
        $arr_str[] = "<span style='    background: #ffffbf;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;'>".$word."</span>";
    }

    return implode(" ",$arr_str);
}

$input_string = "<p>Berdasarkan gambarajah di bawah,nyatakan pecahan tersebut.<br />2/5</p><p> </p>";
echo generate_answer_span($input_string);
```

---

Now, as you can see on the red circle was the weird things have came out. "Uoh very bad...".

How I can filter all the input strings? My expected result that I would like to reset the strings like the string output came from `paste to notepad` then it would be ok.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Use `preg_split('/<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+/', $str)`

Comment: "tersebut.2/5" combined together. I hope that it would be separate. Thanks ;)

Comment: Well, try [`preg_split('/<[^>]+>(?:\s+<[^>]+>)*|\s+/u', $str)`](https://ideone.com/UAYrp3) (it splits on (consecutive) tags, too). No need to use `$word = strip_tags($word);` then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function generate_answer_span($str="")
{
    $words = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', ' ', $str);
    //$arr_words = preg_split('/ +/', trim($words));
    $arr_words = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($words));

    foreach($arr_words as $word)
    {
        $word = strip_tags($word);
        $arr_str[] = "<span style='background: #ffffbf; border: 1px solid #cecece;'>".$word."</span>";
    }

    return implode(" ",$arr_str);
}
```

First you replace the tags with the space and then split the words by the space.

Comment: Wow, the outputs was so nice...can you explain what you have done?

Comment: well, like I said, First I replaced the tags with the space and then split the words by the spaces. I just edited answer to allow for new lines between the input string too. P.S. Can you please accept the answer if it worked for you, please?

Comment: Good IDEA! I need to implement it first to my codes. I will give feedback later on since there are a lots input types will be come. ;) Cheers...